# Recursively apply .passthrough() to a zod schema

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm working with an api that can return complex nested data structure and which is often changing (adding new data, ...).

I want to validate the API return a minimal set of properties but also want to preserve any other attributes (the code should get / update / send back the data).

That's why I use `.passthrough()` in my schema.

This is working well but requires to call the `.passthrough()` on every inner schema one by one to not lose extra property.

Ex:

```js
/* sample data*/
const someObjectFromAnApi = JSON.parse(`{
  "coords": { "x": 42, "y": 0, "z": 30 },
  "color": { "r": 20, "g": 30, "b": 30, "alpha": 0.5 },
  "description": "This is here"
}`);
/* /sample data*/

const dataSchema = z
  .object({
    coords: z
      .object({
        x: z.number(),
        y: z.number()
// I don't need `z`
      })
      .passthrough(), // 1st passthrough
    color: z
      .object({
        r: z.number(),
        g: z.number(),
        b: z.number()
// I don't need 'alpha'
      })
      .passthrough() // 2nd passthrough
  })
// I don't need 'description'
  .passthrough(); //3rd passthrough
```

My question is: is there any (simple) way to either apply `.passthrough()` recursively or default some zod behavior ?

PS: full repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-kilby-4mf4yr?file=/src/index.ts

I tried to add utility file like this:

```js
import { z, ZodType } from 'zod';

type ZObject = typeof z.object;

declare module 'zod' {
    export interface ZodType {
      objectPassthrougth : ZObject;
    }
}

z.ZodObject.prototype.objectPassthrougth = function(shape, params){
  return z.object(shape,params).passthrough();
}

const schema =   
  z.objectPassthrougth({
    some : z.string()
  })
```

but something is wrong in my syntax (not sure what)